Proper shm_size for a Docker container that will spawn multiple Google Chrome browsers
Currently, I´m working on a FastAPI app running via Uvicorn inside a Docker container. The app internally scrapes data from a website (let´s say similar to Wikipedia for the sake of the example) using Selenium to interact with a headless Google Chrome browser.
I want to implement replication into the app using Gunicorn with Uvicorn workers instead of plain Uvicorn (as seen on the docs ) to improve the performance for simultaneous requests but I´m worried about potential crashes if the number of Uvicorn workers (and therefore web browsers) is too high and I end up running low on the shm_size.
Disclaimer: I do not plan to replicate at the cluster level because it's too soon to mess with swarm or k8s (I´m still learning) and my use case complies with the Docker compose case stated on the docs

I´m worried about the shm_size because Chrome doesn't run properly using Docker´s default value. My baseline is the Selenium Standalone with Chrome Docker image in which they recommend using 2 GB for images containing a browser (this setting works for me at the moment), but I have seen other official images with Chrome using 512MB and 1 GB and I don't know which could be a proper combination for the number of workers & shm_size
Disclaimer 2: I would rather not use the Chromedriver flag --disable-dev-shm-usage because of the possible performance decrease.
I´ll do some tests expecting to find a functional value for the shm_size & Uvicorn workers, but I would also like to know:

Are my worries founded and my understanding of the shm_size proper for this scenario?
Would you recommend another starting point for fine-tuning the parameter? (Not 2GB)
What should I be aware of for a proper assessment of the loads(for example the web page contents, the number of workers, etc.), and how to measure/get a value from them?
How can I monitor the /dev/shm usage for fine-tuning its size?

